# What is the password hashing method in Laravel Voyager?

Tags: php, laravel, password-hash, voyager

I have a `voyager` admin panel. I can create or edit users using this admin panel.

Now I want to `signup` or `signin` an user from my frontend website. My question is what is the password encryption method, `voyager` used in their admin panel for creating new user or log in ?

I have already read [this article](http://github.com/the-control-group/voyager/issues/548)

And using hashing algorithm according to [Laravel Hashing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/hashing)

But not solved.

**My function is**

```
public function register(Request $request)
{

    $data = User::where('email','=',$request->email); 

    if (Hash::check($request->password, $data->password))
    {
        echo "success";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "still not";
    }
}
```

**It gives error**

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::$password

Comment: @emix..... Thanks buddy :)

Comment: Laravel's hashing method: https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager/issues/548

Comment: `Bcrypt` Algorithm which is Hashing algorithm not an encryption algorithm

Comment: @duncan...I have updated my post in details...please check

Comment: @SaadSuri...brother please recheck my updated post

Comment: As your errors shows undefined property for `$request->password` Have you checked it with `dd($request->password);`??

Comment: @HirenGohel...yes brother....I got the string value properly

Comment: I've removed the `encryption` tag from this question as it's not actually a question about encryption at all, it's a question about password hashing (which is a distinct use-case and family of algorithms from cryptographic hash functions).

Answer (score 3):

`$data = User::where('email','=',$request->email)->first();` You forgot to retreive the user. What you have is a query builder so it doesn't have any data on it.